# How to make nav bar horizontal using tailwind, react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm learning tailwind using react and i can't seem to make the navbar horizontal. It even disappears on the Ui at some point. how would you edit the following code to be horizontal?

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="z-50 bg-white">
      <div className="h-10vh flex justify-between lg:py-5 px-20  py -20 border-b">
        <div className="flex items-center flex-1">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-pink-500 "> BOWANA </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="flex gap-8 mr-16 text-[18px]">
            <Link to="/"><li>Home</li></Link>
            <Link to="/"><li>Blogs</li></Link>
            <Link to="/"><li>Services</li></Link>
            <Link to="/"><li>Book An Appointment</li></Link>
            <Link to="/"><li>Contact Us</li></Link>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

I expected a horizontal nav bar, it is vertical

Comment: Shouldn't the `<Link>` component be inside the `<li>`?

Comment: Also, the spacing of the `py -20` class is incorrect. I recommend the [Prettier plugin for Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier) to handle sorting class names.

Answer (score 0):

To make your navbar horizontal, need to change the flex direction of the parent container. Currently, the flex direction is set to the default value of flex-col (column), that's why items are stacked vertically. To make it horizontal, set it to flex-row.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="z-50 bg-white">
      <div className="h-10vh flex justify-between gap-10 lg:py-5 px-20  py-20 border-b">
        <div className="flex items-center flex-1">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-pink-500"> BOWANA </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="flex gap-8 text-black mr-16 text-[18px]">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Blogs</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Book An Appointment</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

Live preview: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-agz5wk?file=src%2FNavbar.tsx`
[image]
I resolved the code issue and also defined the black color for `li` and for anchor/routing you need to read about React Routes and in react routes library you will see `Link`
Read more: `https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to swap your `<Link>` and `<li>` nesting. You can also eliminate the `<div>` surrounding your `<ul>`.

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="z-50 w-full bg-white">
      <div className="h-10vh flex gap-8 border-b px-4 py-4 lg:py-5">
        <div className="flex flex-1 items-center">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-pink-500">BOWANA</h2>
        </div>
        <ul className="flex items-center justify-between gap-8 text-[18px]">
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/blogs">Blogs</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/services">Services</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/appointments">Book An Appointment</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact Us</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Navbar.jsx
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="z-50 bg-white">
      <div className="h-10vh flex items-center px-20 py-20 border-b">
        <div className="flex items-center flex-1">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-pink-500 ">BOWANA</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="flex items-center justify-between space-x-6 text-[18px]">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Blogs</Link>
            </li>

            <li>
              <Link to="/">Services</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Book An Appointment</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Contact Us</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

[image: Horizontal Nav Bar]

[image: Edit empty-dust-5nj479]